# Laravel Storage::disk()->url(); does not work properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Hello i have a trouble in laravel.

i wanna create private storage for some stuff (xls,image,pdf, etc). 
Everything works great in storage/app/public directories but i dont want it, i want my directory like storage/app/products/{id}/

at first look at my code:

**filesystem.php**

```
   'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
      'productions' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/productions'),
        'visibility' => 'private',
    ],
```

i create new array 'productions'

**ProductionController.php**

```
public function file()
{

   return '<img src="'.Storage::disk('productions')->url('7/2.png').'">';

}
```

**web.php (Route)**

```
Route::group([
'middleware'=>'roles',
'roles'=>['Administrator','Prefabrykacja','Dyrektor Prefabrykacji']
], function () {
    Route::get('/Produkcja',[
        'uses'=>'ProductionController@index',
        'as'=>'production.index']);
    Route::post('/Produkcja/create',[
        'uses'=>'ProductionController@create',
        'as'=>'production.create']);


    Route::get('/Produkcja/file',[
        'uses'=>'ProductionController@file',
        'as'=>'production.file']);
});
```

if i return

```
return '<img src="'.Storage::disk('productions')->url('7/2.png').'">';
```

Or

```
return '<img src="'.Storage::disk('local')->url('7/2.png').'">';
```

result is the same. both line return the image from storage/app/public/7/2.png will display not image storage/app/products/7/2.png

how can i display the image from my products folder and restrict resources to specifed role?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you're probably missing a symlink like this one for `public` ([Local URL Host Customization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#obtaining-disk-instances)). Also, you need to specify `url` parameter like for `public` and change `visibility` to `public` in order to allow others to see your files.

**filesystem.php:**

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'productions' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/productions'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/productions', // added line (directory within "public")
        'visibility' => 'public', // modified visibility
    ],
],
```

Also make sure that you create a symlink at `public/productions` which will point to `storage/app/productions` directory. You can do this by using following command (for example):

```
cd LARAVEL_PATH && ln -s storage/app/productions public/productions
```

Comment: if i do Storage::disk('productions')->put('file.txt', 'Contents'); everything is ok, they create file.txt in storage/app/productions an put the "Contents" in it but still cant read image from that directory. before i use command php artisan storage:link, if i trying your command it saying me "ln: failed to create symbolic link 'public/productions': No such file or directory" i was try adapt your command to my project.

Comment: How looks like your LARAVEL_PATH root directory? Provide a pastebin link with `ls -la LARAVEL_PATH` output.